# Internet Explorer Bookmarks Directory

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Must be an FAQ but I couldn't find it. I am using Windows 7. I was using IE8 and now use IE11. I would like to search my bookmarks and I think the best way is to use the File Explorer search box. In what path are the bookmarks kept?

Comment: Same location IE has stored them since well forever. `C:\Users\**YourUserNameHere**\Favorites`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Firefox and Chrome, IE keeps all bookmarks as individual links under:

`C:\Users\<your user profile directory>\Favorites`